# Rewrite collecting list of list with java 8 (create clusters)

Tags: java, collections, java-8, grouping, java-stream

I have something like below written as an "old-school" version where I am trying to collect and group similarities in a given `List`. I would like to transfer this solution into, I think better, `functional` way with `grouping` or something more `java 8 stream` way.

Actually I would like to get rid of initialization for `List<List<T>> listOfLists = new LinkedList<List<T>>();` and passing of this instance to `getMatchedList` method.

Here is my current solution:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String... args) {

        List<Integer> originalList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 4, 5, 7);

        List<List<Integer>> listOfLists = new LinkedList<>();
        originalList.stream()
                .forEach(item -> {
                    Optional<List<Integer>> list = getMatchedList(item, listOfLists);
                    if (list.isPresent()) {
                        list.get().add(item);
                    } else {
                        listOfLists.add(new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(item)));
                    }
                });
        System.out.println(listOfLists);
    }

    static Optional<List<Integer>> getMatchedList(Integer item, List<List<Integer>> list) {
        return list.stream().filter(a -> matched(a, item)).findAny();
    }

    static boolean matched(List<Integer> list, Integer b) {
        return list.stream().filter(x -> isSimilar(x, b)).findAny().isPresent();
    }

    static boolean isSimilar(Integer a, Integer b) {
        return Math.abs(a - b) <= 1; // true or false based on additional logic
    }

}
```

Let's say isSimilar function is `Math.abs(a - b) <= 1`.
As a result I would like to have list of lists as follow:

```
[
   [1,2],
   [4,5],
   [7]
]
```

**Note:** For example if we have `1,2,3` we should have list: `[1,2,3]` despite of that `1` and `3` are not similar. But they are "connected" with common similarity which is `2`.

**Note II:** The question is not about the numbers. Numbers are just for simplicity. Actually I have custom objects not `Integers` and I also have different `isSimilar` function. The goal is to achieve this "grouping" to clusters in `java-8 functional` way.

Comment: What if *a* is similar to *b* and *b* is similar to *c* but *a* is not similar to *c*?

Comment: @shmosel if we have `1,2,3` where `1` is `a`, `2` is `b` and `3` is `c` based on your note we should get one list as follow: `[1,2,3]`

Comment: Does your code do that?

Comment: I think it does ... I updated code b/c i had mistakes in getMatchedList function. Code should work I added working sample.

Comment: But 1 and 3 are not similar, so how can they be in the same set?

Comment: You are right `1` and `3` are not similar but they are "connected" with `2`. List is something like cluster.

Comment: It sounds like for every given position in the original list ```x``` you want to create a list of any other number ```y``` in the original list as long as the original list contains all numbers in the range ```[min(x,y) ... max(x,y)]```. If so please state this clearly in your question; currently your explanation is cryptic at best but I think is actually erroneous (e.g. I think you meant ```Math.abs(x - y)``` rather than ```Math.abs(x, y)```.

Comment: Actually a simpler way to state the above, you want to create list of maximal "runs" of consecutive numbers.

Comment: I don't think the most efficient solution would be based on Streams at least not fully. Best is to sort the numbers (perhaps using a stream if you like) and then just iterate once across the sorted list find out where the discontinuities are dumping the run right before the discontinuity into the output list.

Comment: @ValentinRuano yes, you are right. Actually I had correct `Math.abs(a - b)` in the implementation but not in the description. BTW it's not about the numbers. Numbers are just for simplicity. Actually I have custom objects not `Integers` and I also have different `isSimilar` function. The goal is to achieve this "grouping" to clusters in `java-8` functional way.

Comment: @VladoDemcak.... so we can NOT assume that isSimilar is transitive correct? only that is reflexible and reciprocal?

Comment: @ValentinRuano `isSimilar` is some function which returns `boolean` based on relationship we have between two items. This function has to define measurable relationship between two items.

Comment: Your result relies on the order, i.e. if the input is `1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 3, 6`, you don’t get `[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]`, but rather `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7]]`. Stream operation are usually not suitable for such order dependent operations or require additional effort to be correct. Besides, I recommend reading [When to use LinkedList over ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/322715/2711488)…

Comment: If ```isSimilar``` is not a transitive function, meaning that ```isSimilar(x, y) && isSimilar(y,z)``` does not imply  ```isSimilar(x, z)``` then would be rather difficult to get a decent implementation using Streams. If ```isSimilar``` is transitive, the you could use ```reduce``` to keep adding elements to a set of similarity/"equivalence" groups.

Comment: Streams are appropriate when each element can be processed independently. But that isn't the case here; the handling of each element depends on the content of the whole stream. So, don't use streams for this class of problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand what you want to do in OP:  get rid of initialization for `List<List<T>> listOfLists = new LinkedList<List<T>>()`... but don't know why. Here is my answer, maybe is not exactly what you want. First I would like improve a bit of readability from my personal aspect:

```
public void test_45551110() {
    List<Integer> originalList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 4, 5, 7);

    List<List<Integer>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<>();
    originalList.stream().forEach(item -> getMatchedList(item, listOfLists).add(item));
    System.out.println(listOfLists);
}

static List<Integer> getMatchedList(Integer item, List<List<Integer>> listOfLists) {
    return listOfLists.stream().filter(a -> matched(a, item)).findAny().orElseGet(() -> {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        listOfLists.add(list);
        return list;
    });
}
```

Secondly, if the original elements in the list can be sorted based on some property. Your concerns can be easily resolved by [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex)

```
List<List<Integer>> res = StreamEx.of(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 5, 7, 3))
        .sorted().collapse((a, b) -> isSimilar(a, b), Collectors.toList()).toList();
System.out.print(res); // output: [[1, 2, 3], [5], [7]]
```

I think most of people may be concern the time complexity n ^ 2 more than getting rid of initialization for `List<List<T>> listOfLists = new LinkedList<List<T>>()`. if you could share the real data structure and logic in isSimilar, we may be able to figure out the real/better solution for your question.